# how to set item title in UITabBarController when item is another UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I created a `UITabBarController` using storyboard which has 3 items, the first two being view controllers.  I need the third item to point to another `UITabBarController` which has other view controller items.

In the first `UITabBarController`, I can easily set the ITEM titles for the first two view controller items, but how can I set the title of the the `UITabBarController` item, which is the third item, either programatically or using Storyboard?

Using `Xcode 5` and `iOS 7`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from Apple's documentation on the `UITabBarController` class:

> When deploying a tab bar interface, you must install this view as the root of your window. Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar interface should never be installed as a child of another view controller.

So what this means is that you can't nest a UITabBarController inside another UITabBarController. Apple doesn't support this, and if you try to do it you may have unforeseen problems. Also when I tried this very setup using a storyboard just now, I was only able to even see both tab bars when running with iOS 6. Under iOS 7, only the first tab bar even showed up. So you can see that when Apple tells you that you shouldn't do this, it's because they may change the implementation in a way that would break it, and they apparently did.

Comment: under ios 7, I could get both tab bars show up, one on top of the other and working but I could not get the ITEM title to change.  I guess I'll have to re-design it

Answer (score 0):

If the your tab bar controller is root view controller, to set the title of 3rd tab you can try:

```
YourAppDelegateClass *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)appDelegate.window.rootViewController;
[[tabController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setTitle:@"YOUR TITLE"];
```